# Echoing a URL is including host domain name

Tags: php

I'm currently using a custom CMS to display contact information for clients.

When I echo a clients URL it also adds in the host domain name too.

This is the code currently in use:-

```
<a href="<?php $this->_($this->data['url']); ?>" target="_blank">
     <?php $this->_($this->data['url']); ?>
</a>
```

From my understanding this should just show the URL? I.e. client.com but instead it shows as cms.com/client.com

Why does this method also include the domain/host name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is starting with the hostname and is being treated as a relative URL with the hostname being part of the path.

```
 <a href="example.com/foo/bar">
```

If you want to link to a different hostname then you need to either use an absolute URL (with the scheme)

```
<a href="https://example.com/foo/bar">
```

… or a scheme relative URL (which preserves HTTPS or HTTP from the URL of the current page).

```
<a href="//example.com/foo/bar">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and examples.